# selecting from multiple tables where a condition is true

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to run some SQL with no luck, trying to select data from two tables where a condition is true.

The tables are driver_details and locations. Both tables have the column user_id, and I want to get data from both based on the matched user_id from the between part. (that select statement works and returns ID's);

```
SELECT driver_details.firstName,
                    locations.lat,
                    locations.lng
                    FROM driver_details
                    INNER JOIN locations
                    WHERE user_id = 
                    (SELECT user_id FROM locations WHERE 
                    (lat BETWEEN 0 AND 5) AND 
                    (lng BETWEEN 0 AND 5))
```

I am getting the error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\vector\www\scripts\getDriversInRange.php on line 33

Comment: sorry thats just a typo here

Comment: Are you getting an error or incorrect/no data?

Comment: getting a complete error

Comment: Please post the error in your question

Comment: Are you sure that your subquery (the second `SELECT` statement) will always return 1 result and ONLY 1 result? If not, you should probably change `WHERE user_id = ` to `WHERE user_id IN`

Comment: is this not possible for multiple results?

Comment: No, by using `=` instead of `IN`, you're limiting yourself to just one result. See the answer that I just posted. I think it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d.firstName,
    l.lat,
    l.lng
FROM driver_details d
    INNER JOIN locations l ON d.user_id = l.user_id
WHERE l.lat BETWEEN 0 AND 5
    AND l.lng BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

This is basically a more complete example of what BWS posted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to RELATE the 2 tables being JOINed using SOMETHING that's common in both tables, which is used to connect them ... you mention user_id

```
...
FROM driver_details
INNER JOIN locations
ON driver_details.user_id = locations.user_id
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Technically you don't have to. It functions as a `CROSS JOIN`. That said, it's confusing and should be avoided. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16471286/2136840