# Consecutive joins without on clause

Tags: sql

I am reviewing a SQL stored procedure and ran into an issue understanding a section of         joins.  Can anyone please advise on how these joins work without using a "ON" clause?

```
 FROM
       SQL.TableA A LEFT JOIN SQL.TableB B LEFT JOIN SQL.TableC C 
               ON B.ITEMID = C.ITEMID
```

Comment: What DBMS?  There's different kinds of SQL.

Comment: It is valid to do joins this way, but it looks like there's a missing `On` clause after `On B.ItemId = C.ItemId`.  Can you show the full statement?

Comment: Is it possible that `SQL.TableA` can only be a single row?

Comment: @GordonLinoff has discussed [this previously](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16471286/2589202)

Comment: What @RBarryYoung is looking for is something like sql server, mysql, sqlite, oracle... something like that.

Comment: Did you try testing it on some test tables to analyze the results?  Did you check the manual of your DB product to see what the default behavior is for JOINs with no ON clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query could be translated to

```
FROM
   SQL.TableA A LEFT JOIN 
   SQL.TableB B ON B.ITEMID = C.ITEMID LEFT JOIN
   SQL.TableC C ON B.ITEMID = C.ITEMID
```

which as you can see does not make a lot of sense as A isn't being joined
I would expect something like:

```
FROM
   SQL.TableA A LEFT JOIN 
   SQL.TableB B LEFT JOIN
   SQL.TableC C ON B.ITEMID = C.ITEMID
   ON A.ITEMID = C.ITEMID
```

Or it would be valid query written in this form

```
FROM
   SQL.TableA A LEFT JOIN 
   SQL.TableB B LEFT JOIN
   SQL.TableC C ON ColumnThatAandBTablesHave = C.ITEMID
```