# Inner Join Not Showing All Results

Tags: sql-server, join

Could someone kindly assist in troubleshooting a query problem:
I have 2 tables with a common field CheckID.
When I run Select statements as below I get the correct results 2 rows but when I use an inner join, it only returns one row.
I am trying to transition from MS Access to SQL Server, so I am missing something here?
Any assistance highly appreciated.
The tables currently contain these two rows

```
Select CheckID from table1 where CheckID = 723 or CheckID = 322 'returns 2 rows
Select CheckID from table2 where CheckID = 723 or CheckID = 322 'returns 2 rows

Select CheckID from table1 inner join table2 
on table1.CheckID = table2.CheckID ' returns only 1 row
```

Comment: Nothing looks wrong to me, what is the datatype of the CheckID columns in both table1 and table2?

Comment: Can you prove that with a example

Comment: @NoDisplayName this was my example :(

Comment: @RhysJones Data Types are AutoNumber in Table1 and Int in Table2. Are these the same data type in SQL Server?

Comment: @Avagut - I mean sample data

Comment: An Access AutoNumber is an int so this should be fine. You might have to experiment with a LEFT JOIN and a WHERE clause to see what's not matching.

Comment: I have tried a left join and nothing is coming up unmatched. I will recreate both tables and see if works properly.

Comment: I have dropped the tables and created them afresh. Query is working now, I have no clue what that was about. Many thanks. I shall mark this one down to Designer inexperience. Just out of interest is there a data type specific for auto number in SQL Server?

Answer (score -1):

You are selecting only CheckID from table1.

Try this for your purposes:

```
Select CheckID.table1, CheckID.table2 from table1 inner join table2 
where table1.CheckID = 123 or table2.CheckID = 345;
```

Comment: Hi, this is giving me 2 columns, I was hoping to only see the CheckID in table 1 that are matched, still not showing

Comment: SQL Joins - as name says - joins tables. So if you join table1 and table2 then select their id's colmun - you gonna have 2 columns.

Comment: @DamianMąsior This doesn't help answer the question and your 2nd SELECT is missing the ON clause.

Comment: @RhysJones there is no require to use ON clause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470942/can-i-use-mysql-join-without-on-condition .

Comment: @DamianMąsior - that link is for MySQL. The ON clause is not optional in SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you @DamianMąsior, I think I had a problem in my tables, I recreated them and the query worked. Many thanks for the assistance and the information!