# How to Join same table in laravel

Tags: laravel, join, inner-join, laravel-5

I wan to wirte a join query to connect same table, and without `ON`, but when i write it in laravel without on it is showing error

```
$key = DB::table('api_keys as ak')  
->join('api_keys as bk','') 
              ->where('ak.api_key', $api_key)->where('ak.user_id',0)
              ->pluck('api_key');
```

want to build the below query,

```
SELECT * FROM `api_keys` as ak
  JOIN `api_keys` as bk
 WHERE ak.`api_key`=$akey
   and ak.`user_id`=$auser
   and bk.`user_id`=$bsuer
   and bk.`api_key`=$bkey
```

Answer (score 2):

You must provide an `ON` clause for the join. More about where `ON` clauses are required can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16471286/1614398).

You can view the generated query using toSql() on a QueryBuilder object:

```
echo $key = DB::table('api_keys as ak')  
    ->join('api_keys as bk','') 
    ->where('ak.api_key', $api_key)->where('ak.user_id',0)
    ->toSql();
```

Which in your case returns:

```
select * from `api_keys` as `ak` inner join `api_keys` as `bk`
on `` `` where `ak`.`api_key` = ? and `ak`.`user_id` = ?
```

In your case it isn't totally clear what you are trying to achieve, but you might consider joining on `api_key` or the primary key of the `api_keys` table, if that is different:

```
$key = DB::table('api_keys as ak')  
    ->join('api_keys as bk','ak.api_key', '=', bk.api_key) 
    ->where('ak.api_key', $api_key)->where('ak.user_id',0)
    ->pluck('api_key');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DB::table('registerusers as a')
  ->join('registerusers as b', 'a.id', 'b.refer_id')
  ->where('a.username', 'b.username')
  ->where('b.id', 'a.refer_id')
  ->value('b.id');
```

Comment: Don't Make too complex when it can be easy.

Answer (score 1):

without using on clause in laravel query builder you can use following

```
$key = DB::table(DB::raw('api_keys as ak, api_keys as bk'))
          ->where('ak.api_key', '=', $api_key)
          ->where('ak.user_id','=',0)
          ->where('ak.PK','=','bk.PK')
          ->pluck('ak.api_key')
```

where PK references to your table's primary key.
result will in your case.

```
select * from api_keys as ak, api_keys as bk where ak.api_key= 'api_key_value' and ak.user_id = 0 and ak.PK = bk.PK
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating my own class and starting out with a base query which I modify to apply the join (using Laravel's `joinSub` function) as follows:

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->query = DB::table('question_responses as BASE');
}

public function applyFilter($questionId, $questionValue) {
    $filterTableStr = 'filter_table_'.$questionId;
    $filterIdStr = 'filter_id_'.$questionId;
    $filterQuery = DB::table('question_responses AS '.$filterTableStr)
        ->select('survey_response_id AS '.$filterIdStr)
        ->where($filterTableStr.'.question_short_name', $questionId)
        ->where($filterTableStr.'.value', $questionValue);

    $resultTableStr = 'result_table_'.$questionId;
    $this->query = $this->query
        ->joinSub($filterQuery, $resultTableStr, function($join) use ($resultTableStr, $filterIdStr) {
            $join->on('BASE.survey_response_id', '=', $resultTableStr.'.'.$filterIdStr);
        });
}
```

After applying my required filters I can just call `$this->query->get()` as normal to obtain the result.

The important part was to make sure that each resulting table and join fields has unique names.
With this method I can apply unlimited filters to my base query.