# Efficient product of columns in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am wondering whether it is possible via a Pandas function to achieve the following. Given two Pandas DataFrames, get a new DataFrame whose columns are the Cartesian product of the columns in the two given DataFrames. That is, in a simple example, if we have the two DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [1,2]], columns = ['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3,4], [3,4]], columns = ['c', 'd'])
```

which look like

```
df1                 df2
   a  b                c  d
0  1  2             0  3  4
1  1  2             1  3  4
```

I am looking for a function that provides , without looping, the following:

```
df
   a_c  a_d  b_c  b_d
0  3    4    6    8
1  3    4    6    8
```

Comment: wouldn't the cartesian product be something else, like (1,3) (1,4) (2,3) (2,4) \\ (1,3) (1,4) (2,3) (2,4) ?
 See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35268188/4248972 for an answer

Comment: i changed a tag to `numpy` in order to attract Numpy experts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an option:

```
dfjoin = pd.concat((df2.mul(y, axis=0) for _, y in df1.iteritems()), axis=1, keys=df1)
# This next line courtesy of MaxU's comment:
dfjoin.columns = dfjoin.columns.map('_'.join)
dfjoin
   a_c  a_d  b_c  b_d
0    3    4    6    8
1    3    4    6    8
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this get the columns' content correctly. But is it possible to also get the columns in a uni-dimensional index?

Comment: @splinter, try this `r.columns = r.columns.swaplevel().map('_'.join)`, where `r` is a resulting DF

Comment: @MaxU, precisely!

Answer (score 3):

You could do use `pd.concat` with `add_prefix` and `mul` `df2` with `df1`'s series(s).

```
In [806]: pd.concat([df2.mul(df1[c], axis=0).add_prefix(c+'_') for c in df1], axis=1)
Out[806]:
   a_c  a_d  b_c  b_d
0    3    4    6    8
1    3    4    6    8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a NumPy approach using `broadcasting` working with the underlying array data with focus on performance efficiency -

```
out = (df2.values[:,None] * df1.values[:,:,None]).reshape(df1.shape[0],-1)
cols = [i+'_'+j for i in df1.columns for j in df2.columns]
df_out = pd.DataFrame(out, columns = cols)
```

Comment: this is brilliant !

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for adding NumPy tag!