# Create a dataframe from permutation of two columns from two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

There are two dataframes which look like the below:

df_1:

```
    A1
0    2023-12-30
1    2023-12-31
```

df_2:

```
      B1    B2      B3
501  Sam    159cm   300gm
502  Tam    175cm   400gm
```

I want to make another dataframe with the combination of these two. The result should look like below:

df_result:

```
    A1            B1      B2      B3
0  2023-12-30     Sam    159cm   300gm
1  2023-12-31     Sam    159cm   300gm
2  2023-12-30     Tam    175cm   400gm
3  2023-12-31     Tam    175cm   400gm
```

That means, every row of df_2 should be repeated for each element in df_1['A1'] (index is not my concern, anything is accepted).  I did it succesfully using a `for loop`. But it takes a long time when the dataframe is large. Is there any pythonic/pandas way for it?

Comment: How did you know in df_1 2023-12-30 should match with Sam in df_2, have you skipped an ID column or something?

Comment: `df_1.merge(df_2, how='cross')` read following post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699012/performant-cartesian-product-cross-join-with-pandas

Comment: @dimButTries there is nothing to match between these two dfs. It just repeats for each and every value of df_1['A1]

Comment: Unfortunatly the question is closed so no answer can be made. I found the best solution is, first create a dummy/temporary column in both of the dataframes with the same name. Then join them as cross product and finally drop the dummy column. For details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35268188/12243638

Comment: @EMT that's why the question is closed, it's already answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the dataframes into a dictionary and use 'update':

```
df_1_dict = df_1.to_dict()
df_2_dict = df_2.to_dict()

df_1_dict.update(df_2_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
cols = df_1.columns.append(df_2.columns)
out = df_2.merge(df_1, how='cross')[cols]
```

out:

```
    A1          B1  B2      B3
0   2023-12-30  Sam 159cm   300gm
1   2023-12-31  Sam 159cm   300gm
2   2023-12-30  Tam 175cm   400gm
3   2023-12-31  Tam 175cm   400gm
```

However, this method is simple, but it will take quite a time if your DataFrame is too large.

**Example Code**

```
import pandas
data1 = {'A1': {0: '2023-12-30', 1: '2023-12-31'}}
data2 = {'B1': {501: 'Sam', 502: 'Tam'}, 
         'B2': {501: '159cm', 502: '175cm'}, 
         'B3': {501: '300gm', 502: '400gm'}}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But not even the example code has worked on my machine and showed MergeError: : No common columns to perform merge on. Maybe it is worth to mention that my pandas version is 1.1.5.

Comment: @EMT I think it's also a good idea to check the official documentation of the function yourself. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html