# What index should be created?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-optimization

I am following an online database course and I got this question.

Assume I have tables USER, CHECKIN and PLACE.

USER(uid, uname, ucity), uid is the primary key.

PLACE (pid, pname, pxcoord, pycoord, pcity), pid is the primary key.

CHECKIN (uid, pid, cdate, ctime), (uid, cdate, ctime) is the primary key.

The query is

```
select c.uid, c.pid c.cdate
from user u join checkin c join place p 
where ucity='NewYork' and pcity='Chicago'
```

Only allowed to create up to two index structures, what is the best choice and why?

Comment: Looks like an invalid query to me. Why do we need an unconditional join?

Comment: @Basilevs - the query is valid in MySQL. It just might not do what's intended to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470942/can-i-use-mysql-join-without-on-condition

Comment: That's what I mean. Cartesian product of cities, visits and users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exactly that query, create an index on `ucity` and one on `pcity`.

Also, if you're allowed to create up to 2 indexes, maybe you're allowed to also modify one. If that's the case, modify the primary key on the `CHECKIN` table to also contain `pid`, right after `uid`, because most probably in the near future you'll transform this query from a [cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16471286/459233) in an inner or left join

Comment: Could you explain why not create index on uid and pid, as they are join keys?

Comment: They're not join keys in this query. This query is a cross join query (a cartesian product between all rows of those 3 tables) because you don't have on clauses with your JOINs

Comment: Ok, so if it is the natural join, should we first consider index on join keys then keys in where clause?

Comment: That's right. And, if you have to chose just one of the ucity or pcity columns to index, chose the one in the table that has more rows.