# how to get values form two or more table in php mysql using session id

Tags: php, mysql

i create 2 tables, student and class. and also i used stud_id as a foreign key in class table....
how i get both tables values using stud_id???? also i am using stud_id in session....

```
{<?php

 $id=$_SESSION["Stud_id"];

 $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM student where Stud_id='$id'");

 if (!$query)
 {
 die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    echo "<tr><td> Student ID:</td><td> " . $row["Stud_id"]. "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Student Name:</td><td> " . $row["Stud_name"]. "</td>  </tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Password:</td><td> " . $row["password"]. "</td></tr>";

    echo "<tr><td> Father:</td><td> " . $row["Stud_father"]. "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Date Of Birth:</td><td> " . $row["Stud_dob"]. "</td>     </tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Address:</td><td> " . $row["Stud_address"]. "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Gender:</td><td> " . $row["Stud_gender"]. "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Phone No:</td><td> " . $row["Stud_phone"]. "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Class</td><td> " . $row["Stud_class"]. "</td></tr>";


}?>
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Answer (score 3):

Join the tables.  So instead of this structure:

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE ...
```

You'd have this structure:

```
SELECT *
FROM student
INNER JOIN class ON student.stud_id = class.stud_id
WHERE ...
```

This would give you the product of both tables, with all columns from both.

Note that I explicitly left out the `WHERE` clause only so as to not include a [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) vulnerability in an answer.  You're definitely going to want to look into `mysqli` and `PDO` and their use of [prepared statements with query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).  (It's simpler than it sounds.)  Currently your code is open to the most common vulnerability on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to get the results

```
{<?php

 $id=$_SESSION["Stud_id"];

 $query = mysql_query ("select s.*,c.* from student s join class c on s.Stud_id=c.Stud_id where s.Stud_id = '$id'");

 if (!$query)
 {
 die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    echo "<tr><td> Student ID:</td><td> " . $row["s.Stud_id"]. "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Student Name:</td><td> " . $row["s.Stud_name"]. "</td>  </tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Password:</td><td> " . $row["s.password"]. "</td></tr>";

    echo "<tr><td> Father:</td><td> " . $row["s.Stud_father"]. "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Date Of Birth:</td><td> " . $row["s.Stud_dob"]. "</td>     </tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Address:</td><td> " . $row["s.Stud_address"]. "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Gender:</td><td> " . $row["s.Stud_gender"]. "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Phone No:</td><td> " . $row["s.Stud_phone"]. "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td> Class</td><td> " . $row["s.Stud_class"]. "</td></tr>";


}?>
```

**edit**
you may have to change the column names above

Comment: That will effectively perform a cross join, which doesn't seem desirable. I think your query could use an `ON` statement. See [Can I use mysql JOIN without ON condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470942/can-i-use-mysql-join-without-on-condition).