# inner join statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a database about attractions in TN, here are my tables

[image: Cities table]

[image]

I want to find the number of attractions and the cities name for any given city

And I want to list the name and attractions for a given city
How would I go about doing that?

I tries this for the second one but it did not work

```
SELECT attractions.attraction_Name, Cities.city_Name FROM Cities INNER JOIN attractions WHERE city_ID=1
```

Any suggestions?

This is what I get

[image]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of images.

Comment: Check out GROUP BY, and COUNT().

Comment: What is the Problem with your query? Maybe the missing `on` clause?

Comment: i think you are talking about two result am i right ?

Comment: @knowledge....  Yes, you're right

Comment: @Jens I'm not getting an error please take a look at the added image

Comment: try `SELECT attractions.attraction_Name, Cities.city_Name FROM Cities INNER JOIN attractions  on cities_id=City_id WHERE city_ID=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i mentioned in my comment: You miss the `on` clause:

```
SELECT attractions.attraction_Name, Cities.city_Name 
FROM Cities INNER JOIN attractions on cities_ID=city_ID WHERE city_ID=1
```

What you get is called cross product. Every entry of first table is joind with every entry from second table

The Count query can look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Cities.city_Name 
FROM Cities 
INNER JOIN attractions ON attractions.city_ID = Cities.cities_ID
GROUP BY Cities.city_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something more like this for the Counting portion:

```
SELECT COUNT(attractions.attraction_Name), Cities.city_Name 
FROM Cities 
INNER JOIN attractions ON attractions.city_ID = Cities.cities_ID
GROUP BY Cities.city_name
```

And for your other query for listing the attractions and city name:

```
SELECT attractions.attraction_Name, Cities.city_Name 
FROM Cities 
INNER JOIN attractions ON attractions.city_ID = Cities.cities_ID
```

You're missing the `ON` in your join.  Since this is MySQL, [this is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470942/can-i-use-mysql-join-without-on-condition) but now you're making a cross join.

If you want to specify a specific city to select, add a `WHERE` after the `JOIN`, and do something like `WHERE Cities.cities_ID = n` where `n` is the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Your question calls for two queries.

The count of attractions by city:

```
SELECT Cities.city_Name, COUNT(*) number_of_attractions
  FROM Cities
  JOIN attractions ON Cities.cities_ID=attractions.city_ID
 GROUP BY Cities.city_Name
 ORDER BY Cities.city_Name
```

The catalog of all attractions in each city:

```
 SELECT Cities.city_Name, attraction.attraction_Name
  FROM Cities
  JOIN attractions ON Cities.cities_ID=attractions.city_ID
 ORDER BY Cities.city_Name, attraction.attraction_Name
```

You missed two things in your attempt to solve these problems. Firstly, you had a missing ON clause in your JOIN operation.  Without an ON clause JOIN generates all possible pairs of rows from the two tables -- a combinatorial explosion that can drive you bananas.

Secondly, you need the `COUNT(*) ... GROUP BY` pattern for your summary.

(We've all been there.)

Comment: Thank you very much, the first one worked perfectly, but I'm getting all attraction names and cities names for the second one what if I just wanted one city?

Comment: Add your `WHERE cities.cities_ID = 1` clause to limit your query to just one city. Put it before the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

assuming there's one to many relationships between the two tables, you are missing an on clause in your query, but once you join the two tables properly, you could simply filter with a where clause:

```
select c.city_name, a.attraction_name
 from cities c inner join attractions a on a.city_id = c.cities_id
 where city_id = 1;
```