# Combining MySQL querys

Tags: mysql, sql

This SQL tells me how much when the maximum occurred in the last hour, and is easily modified to show the same for the minimum.

```
SELECT
  mt.mB as Hr_mB_Max,
  mt.UTC as Hr_mB_Max_when
FROM
  thundersense mt
WHERE
  mt.mB =(
  SELECT
    MAX(mB)
  FROM
    thundersense mt2
  WHERE
    mt2.UTC >(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() -3600))
  ORDER BY
    utc
  DESC
LIMIT 1
```

How do I modify it so it returns both maximum & minimum and their respective times?

Yours Simon M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question, you are looking to create a 4 column and 1 row answer where it looks like:

```
+-------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
| event | time_it_occured |  event   | time_it_occured |
+-------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
| fun   |           90000 | homework |           12000 |
+-------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
```

**Below is a similar situation/queries you can adapt for your situation.**

So, given a table called 'people' that looks like:

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | name | salary |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | bob  |  40000 |
|  2 | cat  |  12000 |
|  3 | dude |  50000 |
+----+------+--------+
```

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT name, salary FROM people WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM people)) t JOIN
(SELECT name, salary FROM people WHERE salary = (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM people)) a;
```

to generate:

```
+------+--------+------+--------+
| name | salary | name | salary |
+------+--------+------+--------+
| bob  |  40000 | cat  |  12000 |
+------+--------+------+--------+
```

Some things to note:

1. you can change the WHERE clauses to be the ones you have mentioned in question (for MAX and MIN).
2. Please be careful with the above query, here I am using a cartesian join (cross join in MYSQL) in order to get the 4 columns. To be honest, it doesn't make sense for me to get back data in one row but you said that's what you're looking for.

Here is what I would work with instead, getting two tuples/rows back:

```
+----------+--------+
| name     | salary |
+----------+--------+
| dude     | 95000  |
| Cat      | 12000  |
+----------+--------+
```

And to generate this, you would use:

```
(SELECT name, salary FROM instructor WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM instructor))
UNION
(SELECT name, salary FROM instructor WHERE salary = (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM instructor));
```

Also: A JOIN without a ON clause is just a CROSS JOIN. 
[How to use mysql JOIN without ON condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470942/how-to-use-mysql-join-without-on-condition)

Comment: Many thanks for your solutions, they are closer to what I wanted.

Comment: I was surprised to see that there is no saving in time between running 'find max' then 'find min' and using these solutions though. I thought that it might be more efficient to combine the searches

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a `join`:

```
SELECT mt.mB as Hr_mB_Max, mt.UTC as Hr_mB_Max_when
FROM thundersense mt JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(mB) as max_mb, MIN(mb) as min_mb
      FROM thundersense mt2
      WHERE mt2.UTC >(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 3600)
     ) mm
     ON mt.mB IN (mm.max_mb, mm.min_mb)
ORDER BY utc DESC;
```

My only concern is your `limit 1`.  Presumably, the `mB`s should be unique.  If not, there is a bit of a challenge.  One possibility would be to use an auto-incremented id rather than `mB`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Gordon,

Comment: I think I need to make myself a little clearer,  The query I use shows the max from the last hour along with its time stamp. I can re-run the query only looking for the min and its time stamp. What I would like is to get just 1 row of 4 columns: Max with its Time and  Min with its Time.
I thought that I could select all the records from the last hour then query that.