# anything but JOIN creating an SQL syntax error? BUT JOIN quadruples my results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

when using this code:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytablename`
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT wdt_ID, TIMEDIFF (NOW(),mytablename.`Time_stamp`) AS Wait
    FROM `mytablename`
) as t
```

The error is the same when I use a `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, or `FULL OUTER JOIN` but I don't get the error when I use a `JOIN` only statement. That takes what are only 8 results and repeats them over and over for 200 results that are the same. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADD the join condition like for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytablename m
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT wdt_ID
                   , TIMEDIFF (NOW(),Time_stamp)
            FROM mytablename ) as t on m.wdt_ID = t.wdt_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks so much I totally forgot about that portion of the equation. Why does it sort of work while only using JOIN?

Comment: I have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470942/how-to-use-mysql-join-without-on-condition from @GordonLinoff and I believe it will be of help to you...

Comment: Because MySQL [wrongly] interprets a `JOIN` as if it were a `CROSS JOIN`. That strongly deviates from the SQL Standard and I would recommend not to use it. It's confusing for everyone else that is not the author of the code.

Comment: @michael I have to comment that your error in your question is little bi strange ?

Comment: @vboka why? The answer was exactly what you said it was and solved the problem. That was the error out of MYPHPADMIN

Comment: Hi @michael because you do not use 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: True. Not sure. Just what MYPHPADMIN was giving to me. Problem solved though and the good answers explained why it worked unexpectedly with JOIN